# How to initialize data and make data binding work properly in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I learnt from this [tutorial](https://github.com/LetsCreateSeries/TimeTrackerTutorial) and tried to build my own time tracker app using master detail page instead. But I met an issue. Here is a similar quick demo for the issue:

For **MasterDetailPageDetail.xaml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QuickDemo"          
             x:Class="QuickDemo.MasterDetailPageDetail"
             Title="Detail">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="Tab One">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:FirstPage BindingContext="{Binding FirstPageModel}" />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="Tab Two">

        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
  
</TabbedPage>
```

For **FirstPage.xaml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             xmlns:buttons="clr-namespace:QuickDemo.Views.Buttons"
             x:Class="QuickDemo.FirstPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Padding="20,20,20,5">
                <Label Text="{Binding CurrentStartDate, StringFormat='{0:h:mm tt}'}"
                       FontSize="20"
                       TextColor="Black"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding RunningTotal, StringFormat='{}{0:h\\:mm\\:ss}'}"
                       FontSize="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       TextColor="Black"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

For **DetailPageModel.cs**:

```
public class DetailPageModel : PageModelBase
    {
        private FirstPageModel _firstPageModel;
        public FirstPageModel FirstPageModel
        {
            get => _firstPageModel;
            set => SetProperty(ref _firstPageModel, value);
        }

        public DetailPageModel(
            FirstPageModel firstPageModel)
        {
            FirstPageModel = firstPageModel;
        }

        public override Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData = null)
        {
            return Task.WhenAny(base.InitializeAsync(navigationData),
                FirstPageModel.InitializeAsync(null));
        }
    }
```

For **FirstPageModel.cs**:

```
public class FirstPageModel : PageModelBase
    {
        private DateTime _currentStartDate;
        public DateTime CurrentStartDate
        {
            get => _currentStartDate;
            set => SetProperty(ref _currentStartDate, value);
        }

        private TimeSpan _runningTotal;
        public TimeSpan RunningTotal
        {
            get => _runningTotal;
            set => SetProperty(ref _runningTotal, value);
        }

        private Timer _timer;

        public FirstPageModel()
        {
           
            this.InitializeTimer();
        }

        private void InitializeTimer()
        {
            _timer = new Timer();
            _timer.Interval = 1000;
            _timer.Enabled = false;
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
        }

        private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunningTotal += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        }

        public override async Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData)
        {
            CurrentStartDate = DateTime.Now;
            RunningTotal = new TimeSpan();
            await base.InitializeAsync(navigationData);
        }
    }
```

And I registered the page and pagemodel in the **PageModelLocator.cs**:

```
public class PageModelLocator
    {
        static TinyIoCContainer _container;
        static Dictionary<Type, Type> _lookupTable;

        static PageModelLocator()
        {
            _container = new TinyIoCContainer();
            _lookupTable = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

            // Register pages and page models
            Register<DetailPageModel, MasterDetailPageDetail>();
            Register<FirstPageModel, FirstPage>();


            // Register services (services are registered as singletons default)

        }

        public static T Resolve<T>() where T : class
        {
            return _container.Resolve<T>();
        }

        public static Page CreatePageFor(Type pageModelType)
        {
            var pageType = _lookupTable[pageModelType];
            var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
            var pageModel = _container.Resolve(pageModelType);
            page.BindingContext = pageModel;
            return page;
        }

        static void Register<TPageModel, TPage>() where TPageModel : PageModelBase where TPage : Page
        {
            _lookupTable.Add(typeof(TPageModel), typeof(TPage));
            _container.Register<TPageModel>();
        }
    }
```

PageModelBase.cs and ExtendedBindableObject.cs are same as the tutorial. When I ran the emulator, I got this result:

[image]

I thought there would be a DateTime string and a zero time span. I feel like the data in FirstPageModel isn't initialized at all. I also tried to set CurrentStartTime in the constructor. Got the same result.

Did I miss something to display CurrentStartDate and RunningTotal on FirstPage? Any help or hints would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your `MasterDetailPageDetail` is not being initialized (or `BindingContext` set for that matter). The architecture in the tutorial sets the `BindingContext` during a navigation event. Since you are setting the Master and Detail explicitly in the XAML of your `MasterDetailPage`, the Binding Context is not explicitly set and the `InitializeAsync` Method is not being called.

**Add initialization in the Navigation Service**

update `NavigationService`'s `NavigateToAsync` method with the following, right after `if (setRoot)` and before `if (page is TabbedPage tabbedPage)`:

```
if (page is MasterDetailPage mdp)
{
     App.Current.MainPage = mdp;
     // We need to initialize both Master's BindingContext as
     // well as Detail's BindingContext if they are PageModelBases
     if (mdp.Master.BindingContext is PageModelBase masterPM)
     {
         await masterPM.InitializeAsync(null);
     }
     if (mdp.Detail.BindingContext is PageModelBase detailPM)
     {
         await detailPM.InitializeAsync(null);
     }
}
else if (page is TabbedPage tabbedPage) 
// .... existing code here
```

**Make sure you're setting the Binding Context for the Pages (Master and Detail). You can do this in the XAML or by resolving in the MasterDetailPage and PageModel like you did for the Tabbed Page**

I can make a video to cover this if needed, and add it to the Series. Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Patrick

Comment: Hi Patrick. I finally make that works for the detail page as the same way as the tabbed page. But when I click to enter that detail page from the master page menu, it doesn't work. It would be great if you can add this to the Series! Many thanks!